# HLSL without WPF or XNA?

Tags: .net, wpf, xna, directx, hlsl

I have a large scientific legacy application written in VB .NET 4.0, using winforms.  I find the need for pixel shaders.  In order to use pixel shaders in this situation, I assume I have to, for example, launch a WPF form, do some graphics magic, then disappear the form. That seems awkward.  So, my question is "is there a way to use HLSL pixel shaders in a winforms application without WPF or XNA?

Thank you very much.

katherine

Comment: Would this help? http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/DirectX/Csharp/Series3/Pixel_Shader.php

Comment: Are you talking about rendering 2D or 3D graphics in VB.NET using pixel shaders, or scientific computations (no graphics) using GPGPU (General Purpose GPU Computing)?

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson good question! Is the shader needed for visualization or computation?

Comment: ... as if its GPGPU I would look at nVidia CUDA (Cg+nVidia only) or OpenCL (ATI, nVidia, CPU parallism) in that order of preference. I've worked on GPGPU projects before, specifically computation of Fast Fourier Transforms on GPUs. Best regards

Comment: Wouter -- thanks for the link.  I had not found that one.  I will look into it today.

Comment: Andrew -- it is 2D graphics for presentation.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3):

You definitely don't want to use MDX (Managed DirectX is deprecated) or call into native DirectX (reinventing the wheel). You're much better off using [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/) or [SharpDX](http://code.google.com/p/sharpdx/), two open-source and up-to-date libraries.

Likewise, if OpenGL is an option then there's libraries like [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/) for that as well.

Comment: @MattDavey - It is VB.NET 4.0 (see question)

Comment: @Erno yes I see now :) I thought he used VB4!

Comment: @MattDavey - I agree, especially when there is the dreaded "legacy" term in the same sentence. On the other hand, VB 9, 10 isn't helping either as I am losing track of VB version numbers.

Comment: Thanks, guys.  I'll look into SlimDX.  The site says that "Rendering primitives is the raison d’être of a 3D graphics API."  Guess I better take a French class too.

Answer (score 2):

Is HLSL really what you want? If it's a scientific application you might be better of with a more generalized shader language such as [CG](http://developer.nvidia.com/cg-toolkit).

To answer your question though, WPF and XNA require HLSL, but the dependency is only one way. You best bet is probably to fall back to native C++ code and interface with DirectX or OpenGL that way -  this native interface could be integrated with your VB4 app via [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model). It is not a pretty solution, but legacy apps never are :)

EDIT: I just saw that you use VB.NET with .NET 4.0. I thought you used the veeery old Visual Basic 4! In that case, the answers which mention a managed DirectX wrapper (SlimDX) are your best option :)

Comment: Thank you.  Yea, it's legacy, but it's not THAT legacy.  It is .NET 4.0, so by "legacy" I mean I will not get permission to rewrite it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can use HLSL shader without WPF and XNA by using DirectX, You need to create shader file(.fx) then you can use it in C# or VB.NET by using MDX library. [Here](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/DirectX/Csharp/Series3/Vertex_Shader.php) is the sample would help you

Answer (score -1):

You could use native DirectX.  Xna on Windows is basically a DirectX wrapper.  If you use the native DirectX library, you can probably figure most of it out on your own if you are familiar with Xna, but there are many guides.  The hardest part to emulate is the Content Pipeline.

To do so, just download the latest DirectX SDK, install it, and add references to the Microsoft.DirectX.* libraries.

Comment: -1 Microsoft.DirectX.* assemblies are not native DirectX - they are managed DirectX, which are deprecated.

Comment: Thank you...and by the way, I posted this same question on EE and got no response at all in 5 days.  I deleted it.  www.stackoverflow.com rocks.